# Extract content between tags

Tags: sed

I have a file with data as below

[image]
I want to extract the lines and write to another files. The o/p should be

[image]
I want to do this in a unix shell script.

Comment: Get everything between lines 100 and 123: `sed -n '100,123p' datafile`

Comment: Get rid of the tags: `sed -n 's/<start>//gp;s/<end>//gp'`, you might need to escape the `<>` characters with a backslash `\\`

Comment: Please do _not_ post images of text. Copy & paste the text itself, putting it into a code block to preserve formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Your example data can be *almost* transformed as requested like:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' <infile >outfile
```

There is that last trailing `|` pipe thing on the *line6* line. Because your example is apparently a screen shot I'm thinking it is actually your cursor in freeze-frame.

I'm uncertain if it is a mistake or if it is meant to represent an outlier, but, either way, this doesn't handle it. I could make it so, but I would need some clarification on that score.

However, if that's as difficult as it gets, then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/.*\(line[0-9]*\).*/\1/' file > new_file
```

> Input

```
<start>line1<end>
line2
line3<end>
<start>line4
line123
<start>line12<>
<>line<end>
<start>line456
```

> Output

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line123
line12
line
line456
```

It will extract for your any line[digit] from any string